# Not getting value of other attributes using select_related in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to fetch the values from TypingTest model. The foreign key is referencing to the UserProfile model. While fetching the data I want the username to be displayed in the result of the query as well. So, after researching a bit I found out that select_related could be a way of doing this. But when I am trying to use select_related. I am not able to see the username, Only the value of the primary key is getting shown.
These are the two models that I have.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   userName = models.CharField(max_length=26,unique=True)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=254,unique=True)
   profilePhoto = models.ImageField(default="/default.png")
   rank = models.CharField(max_length=26,default="Novice")
   def __str__(self):
       return self.userName
    
class TypingTest(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   time = models.IntegerField()
   wpm = models.IntegerField()
   accuracy = models.IntegerField()
   raw = models.IntegerField()
   dateTaken = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Correspoding serializer class:

```
class TypingTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta : 
    model = TypingTest
    fields =  ('id','user','time','wpm','accuracy','raw','dateTaken')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta :
       model = UserProfile
       fields = ('userName','email','profilePhoto','rank')
```

This is the view code that I have written.

```
@protected_resource()
@api_view(['GET'])
def getAllTests (request):
    testListQuerySet = models.TypingTest.objects.all()
    selectRelated = models.TypingTest.objects.select_related('user').only("userName")
    print(selectRelated.values())
    serializer=serializers.TypingTestSerializer(models.TypingTest.objects.select_related('user'),many=True)    
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

The output that I am getting is :

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'user_id': 3, 'time': 60, 'wpm': 60, 'accuracy': 91, 'raw': 79, 'dateTaken': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 14, 21, 7, 32, 721899, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}, {'id': 2, 'user_id': 4, 'time': 30, 'wpm': 82, 'accuracy': 99, 'raw': 85, 'dateTaken': datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 14, 21, 33, 45, 326814, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}]>
```

Please let me know if this is the right way of doing the thing intended and if not what is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include the `userName` field in the output, you should use the `UserSerializer` to serialize the related `UserProfile` object instead. Currently, you should use the `source` argument to specify the related field name in the `TypingTest` model, and the `UserSerializer` to serialize the related object so:

```py
class TypingTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    userName = serializers.CharField(source='user.userName')
    
    class Meta: 
        model = TypingTest
        fields =  ('id','user','userName','time','wpm','accuracy','raw','dateTaken')
```

Then in view, remove the `select_related` method call as it is not necessary so:

```py
@protected_resource()
@api_view(['GET'])
def getAllTests (request):
    testListQuerySet = models.TypingTest.objects.all()
    serializer = serializers.TypingTestSerializer(testListQuerySet, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

`select_related` is just to fetch related in the same query and preventing to make a new DB hit for accessing FK. Read about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

In order to get user data, you need no get it, and `select_related` cause no more DB hit. You can get it by this way for example:

```py
user = models.TypingTest.objects.select_related('user').first().user
```

And if you want to represent it in your response, you have to add `user` to your seriliazer fields:

```py
class TypingTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TypingTest
        fields = ("user", ...)
```

Comment: It is saying ` 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user'`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get a username of all objects then you have to query like this

```
TypingTest.objects.select_related('user').values('userName')
```